# ivysvn: file organization and passwords

Tags: svn, ivy

I'm looking at using [ivysvn](http://code.google.com/p/ivysvn/) to help us use a local ivy repository in our svn repository.

I found this [tutorial](http://theflashesofinsight.wordpress.com/2010/09/21/maintain-a-local-subversion-repository-for-dependency-management-using-apache-ivy-and-ivysvn/) which I found easy to follow, and almost works, except for 3 points:

1. The tutorial has a blank username and password. How can I get this to work with our SVN repository (which does not allow anonymous commits) without having to put my username and password in the ivysettings.xml or build.xml? The closest I could think of was to use in ivysettings.xml:

   ```
   <svn name="ivysvn"
            repositoryRoot="{{{deleted}}}"
            userName="${svn.user.name}" userPassword="${svn.user.password}" 
            binaryDiff="false">
         <ivy pattern="[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy.xml"/>
         <artifact pattern="[organisation]/[module]/[artifact].[ext]"/>
    </svn>
   ```

   and then at the command prompt do

   ```
   ant -Dsvn.user.name={{{deleted}}} -Dsvn.user.password={{{deleted}}} publish
   ```
2. I thought the organization of the repository was as follows (for example suppose the server URL is http://someserver/svn/cache/ivy , the organization is Yoyodyne, and the module is HappyFunBall)

   ```
   http://someserver/svn/cache/ivy/
     Yoyodyne/
       HappyFunBall/
         1.0/
           ivy.txt
           libraries here
   ```

   This would imply in ivysettings.xml

   ```
       <ivy pattern="[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy.xml"/>
       <artifact pattern="[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]"/>
   ```

   and not

   ```
       <ivy pattern="[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy.xml"/>
       <artifact pattern="[organisation]/[module]/[artifact].[ext]"/>
   ```

   Which is correct? Ideally there would be a mapping of SVN version # to artifact revision, and then you wouldn't need to create [revision] directories, but something doesn't make sense.
3. The blog post had, in the source project, an ivy.xml file with this:

   ```
    <ivy:publish resolver="ivysvn"  forcedeliver="true" 
         overwrite="true" publishivy="false">
           <!-- defines the location from where the libraries 
           are to be picked up from for publishing -->
     <artifacts pattern="lib/[artifact].[ext]"/>
   </ivy:publish>
   ```

   and I think I understand all of it except for the `publishivy="false"` part, since the retrieval part wouldn't work except when I changed it to `publishivy="true"`. Which is correct? Where does the ivy.xml file come in w/r/t putting a copy of it into the repository?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that was a lot to read. lol

Regarding your final question:

> Where does the ivy.xml file come in w/r/t putting a copy of it into the repository?

ivy.xml files (like pom.xml files) work to tell ivy "stuff" about each artifact.  How else would ivy know where to find the dependencies of each JAR?

So, as a broad, general statement, ivies are left out of repositories where either 1) for one reason or another transitive dependencies don't matter (the dependencies of dependencies) or 2) transitive dependencies are determined from some other means (mvnrepo, for example).

Without diving into the depths of your particular situation, I'd say there must be some reason the creators of that tool feel you don't need the ivies.

I hope I've addressed your question about excluding ivies from repositories.